# How to customize seekbar in android with multiple colors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

[image]

I'm trying to customize the seekbar as shown in the image. There is a main color which is green and the user is given option to add bookmark to the video which then gets highlighted as yellow.

I'm stuck at trying to find a direction to proceed with this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3118

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party seek bar plugin from GitHub called "crystal range seek bar", Its nice and easily customisable.
[**check it here**](https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar)